# jqgrid column width auto

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Is there a way that the column width of jqgrid change dynamically according to the content of that column? I used shrinkToFit and autoWidth but non of them worked for me. I use jqgrid 4.5.2. I have searched and read the other questions but those didn't work for me. Maybe there is a widget to do that. I will be thankful if you help me.

Comment: After some progress, I found that if I change table-layout:fixed to table-layout:auto, the column width will fit with the content of that cell. But when I did that, the header is not aligned with the columns any more. Please help if you can.

Comment: For future reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299441/jqgrid-column-auto-width

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implement jqGrid column width based on column content.  Add this to the gridComplete event.

```
$(this).parent().append('<span id="widthTest" />');

gridName = this.id;

$('#gbox_' + gridName + ' .ui-jqgrid-htable,#' + gridName).css('width', 'inherit');
$('#' + gridName).parent().css('width', 'inherit');

var columnNames = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
var thisWidth;

// Loop through Cols
for (var itm = 0, itmCount = columnNames.length; itm < itmCount; itm++) {

     var curObj = $('[aria-describedby=' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ']');

     var thisCell = $('#' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ' div');
     $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.text()).css({
           'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
           'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
           'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
     });
     var maxWidth = Width = $('#widthTest').width() + 24;                    
     //var maxWidth = 0;                      

     // Loop through Rows
     for (var itm2 = 0, itm2Count = curObj.length; itm2 < itm2Count; itm2++) {
          var thisCell = $(curObj[itm2]);

          $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.html()).css({
               'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
               'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
               'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
          });

          thisWidth = $('#widthTest').width();
          if (thisWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = thisWidth;                        
     }                    

     $('#' + gridName + ' .jqgfirstrow td:eq(' + itm + '), #' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name).width(maxWidth).css('min-width', maxWidth);

 }

 $('#widthTest').remove();
```

A working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ba5yK/17/

Hope this helps,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution, but the column widths jump to the initial width when re-sizing.
This is my modified solution as a separate function. Designed to work with shrinkToFit set to false, and fire just once:

```
function setColumnWidths(gridName) {
    if ($('#' + gridName).attr('columnsSet')=='true') return;

    $('body').append('<span id="widthTest">WIDTHTEST</span>');
    $('#gbox_' + gridName + ' .ui-jqgrid-htable,#' + gridName).css('width', 'inherit');
    $('#' + gridName).parent().css('width', 'inherit');

    var containerWidth=$('#' + gridName).width() - 20;
    var columnNames = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
    var thisWidth;

    // Loop through Cols
    for (var itm = 0, itmCount = columnNames.length; itm < itmCount; itm++) {

        var curObj = $('[aria-describedby=' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ']');

        var thisCell = $('#' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ' div');
        $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.text()).css({
            'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
            'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
            'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
        });
        var maxWidth = $('#widthTest').width() + 40;
        //var maxWidth = 0;                      

        // Loop through Rows
        for (var itm2 = 0, itm2Count = curObj.length; itm2 < itm2Count; itm2++) {
            var thisCell = $(curObj[itm2]);

            $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.html()).css({
                'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
                'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
                'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
            });

            thisWidth = $('#widthTest').width();
            if (thisWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = thisWidth;
        }
        if (maxWidth > containerWidth) maxWidth=containerWidth;
        $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('setColProp','amount',{width: maxWidth});
        var gw = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam','width');
        $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('setGridWidth',gw,true);
        $('#' + gridName + ' .jqgfirstrow td:eq(' + itm + '), #' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name).width(maxWidth).css('min-width', maxWidth);

    }
    $('#widthTest').remove();
    $('#' + gridName).attr('columnsSet','true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answered earlier or not but below is solution I implemented which is working one.  Just provide column width in percentage and summation of all column should reach to 100%. But I am not sure how to deal with adding/removing columns at runtime.

I am working on that as well and will update all.

```
 columns: [
     { text: 'CheckBox', datafield: 'ProjectSubstantialPOUADetailsID', width: '10%' },
     { text: 'Area/Phase Substantial', datafield: 'SubstantialPOUA', width: '30%' },

     { text: 'Type', datafield: 'SubstantialTypeName', width: '15%' },
     { text: 'Achieved', datafield: 'DateAchieved', width: '15%', cellsformat: 'd', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y" } },
     { text: 'PL Final', datafield: 'DateFinal', width: '15%', cellsformat: 'd' },
     { text: 'Warranty?', datafield: 'Warranty', width: '15%', columntype: 'checkbox' }
     ]
```

Thanks
Rushi

Answer (score 0):

pphillips001 answer works for me but resizing is to slow when the grid grows. I just updated the logic and the performance is very good now.

```
function setColumnWidths(gridName) {
    if ($('#' + gridName).attr('columnsSet')=='true') return;

    $('body').append('<span id="widthTest">WIDTHTEST</span>');
    $('#gbox_' + gridName + ' .ui-jqgrid-htable,#' + gridName).css('width', 'inherit');
    $('#' + gridName).parent().css('width', 'inherit');

    var containerWidth=$('#' + gridName).width() - 20;
    var columnNames = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
    var thisWidth = 0;

    // Loop through Cols
    for (var itm = 0, itmCount = columnNames.length; itm < itmCount; itm++) {

       var curObj = $('[aria-describedby=' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ']');

        var thisCell = $('#' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ' div');
        $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.text()).css({
           'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
           'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
           'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
        });
        var maxWidth = $('#widthTest').width() + 40;
        //var maxWidth = 0;                      

        // Loop through Rows
        var maxText = 0;
        var theCell;
        for (var itm2 = 0, itm2Count = curObj.length; itm2 < itm2Count; itm2++) {
            thisCell = $(curObj[itm2]);
            if (maxText < thisCell.text().length) {
                maxText = thisCell.text().length;
                theCell = thisCell;
            }
        }
        if (theCell !== undefined) {
            $('#widthTest').html(theCell.html()).css({
                'font-family': theCell.css('font-family'),
                'font-size': theCell.css('font-size'),
                'font-weight': theCell.css('font-weight')
            });

            thisWidth = $('#widthTest').width() + 5;
        }
        if (thisWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = thisWidth;
    if (maxWidth > containerWidth) maxWidth=containerWidth;
    $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('setColProp','amount',{width: maxWidth});
    var gw = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam','width');
    $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('setGridWidth',gw,true);
    $('#' + gridName + ' .jqgfirstrow td:eq(' + itm + '), #' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name).width(maxWidth).css('min-width', maxWidth);

}
$('#widthTest').remove();
$('#' + gridName).attr('columnsSet','true');
```

}

Answer (score -1):

colModel: [ { name: "f_name",index:"f_name",**width:'100%'**} ]